# How to find the current day of the year in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a standard function in PHP that will find the day number of the year based on the current date?

Examples:

```
Jan 22nd = 22 
Feb 27th = 58
Mar 5th = 64
```

If there isn't a standard function, has anyone built anything similar that would handle the conversion?  What all is involved?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`date('z') + 1;`

Answer (score 11):

Use the `z` format character of the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
 echo date('z'); // 22, based on the "current date"
```

Comment: You have to add 1, though, since the value returned is zero-based.

Answer (score 10):

```
// get day of year for 08 aug 2008
// result 221
echo date("z", mktime(0,0,0,8,8,2008))+1;
```