# How to update a css height property based on number of days elapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wanting to update a 'thermometer' that was made in CSS that rises based on the number of days that have elapsed for the fiscal year (Ending June 30).

Currently, I manually update the height by updating the css. For, instance if 328/365 days have elapsed, then it would set to 89.86%.

```
#thermometer .progress {
height:89.86%;
}
```

How can I get the height to update automatically based on how many days have elapsed in the fiscal year?

Comment: What javascript code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the year ends on 30th June, the code should be

```
var now = new Date();
var isLeapYear = //can be googled to find algorithm
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);     
var days_as_percentage_of_year = (((day + (isLeapYear?182:181)) % (isLeapYear?366:365)) / (isLeapYear?366:365)) * 100;

$("#thermometer .progress").css('height', days_as_percentage_of_year + '%');
```

So in this case, 30th June will show at 100% and 31st Dec close to 50%. This merely depicts the logic and might need some adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use javascript/jquery to update the value of the height inline:

```
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);     
var days_as_percentage_of_year = (day / 365) * 100;

$("#thermometer .progress").css('height', days_as_percentage_of_year + '%');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var currentheight = (<?php echo date('z') + 1; ?>/365)*100;
  $('#thermometer .progress').css('height',currentheight+'%');
});
```

Sources

- [How to find the current day of the year in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121782/how-to-find-the-current-day-of-the-year-in-php)
- https://api.jquery.com/ready/
- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp