# How to get a date of number of a day of the year in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm new in PHP, creating an automatic calendar: days in a table:

```
mon tue wed thu fri sat sun weeknum
```

where there are 6 rows (6 weeks). I want the number of days to change every 6 weeks, for example:

today is Mon 1st Jan (the 1st day of calendar), and the last day of the table is Sun 11th Feb (42nd day). Effect I need: at Mon 12th Feb, the numbers are switching +42 (and the Mon 12th Feb is the 1st day of the table, and Sun 25th Mar is the last 42th day).

How to do that? I was thinking about some "ifs" - 
`if $todaydayofyear = $1st_calend_dayofyear +42 -> $1st_calend_dayofyear = $1st_calend_dayofyear + 42`
and so on for each next day e.g. `$7thday = date(day,$1st_calend_dayofyear+6)`
but I don't know how to get a day from (date of (number of the day of the year)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the current day of the year in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121782/how-to-find-the-current-day-of-the-year-in-php)

Comment: Have a look on DateInterval, this is what you need to achieve your goal. And also have a look on date, where you can get any information that you need.

Comment: > Possible duplicate of How to find the current day of the year in PHP? – cale_b 31 secs ago
No, it's not - I want to convert number of the year to a date, not vice versa.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://3v4l.org/6WCVh